# Excel automatic calculation crashes, but manual calculation works

Tags: excel, vba

I have a relatively large (7MB) but more importantly formula and macro heavy excel file that I have been developing recently. 
For the end user it must be able to be used in Automatic Calculation mode.

**While calculating the whole sheet in Manual Calculation mode using F9 (Calculate Now) will work and calculate in ~10 seconds, but when I turn it onto Automatic mode, it will calculate repeatedly** (i.e reaches 100% and then immediately starts again from 0%) and so freezes indefinitely.

So far I have tried:

1. Putting break points in all the VBA macros to see if it is hanging inside a macro
2. Removing all of the macros from the file (I was worried one of them was being triggered to run repeatedly in automatic mode)

but neither has worked leading me to wonder if the issue is not in fact VBA related.

Does anyone have any ideas about:

- What might be causing this?
- How I might diagnose the cause?

Happy to give more context if helpful. I am a relatively experienced excel user, and while generally don't write VBA macros from scratch am pretty confident at re-purposing code I inherit / find online. I am using a relatively powerful 6 core machine, but have tested it on others to the same results.

Comment: Try saving the file as an .xls to be certain that it isnt a macro issue. If the file still hangs as a non-macro enabled file (make sure you close and re-open after saving) then it is a formula issue. If the file doesn't still hang it is a macro issue. My experience with calculations isn't too broad, but if you are having it calculate in a loop like that then either an event is triggering (likely a worksheet event) or your formulas are volatile (any time one value changes, all associated values must recalculate. This is different from Excel's standard 'dirty cells only' approach.

Comment: Unfortunately i'm working in a 64bit .xlsb file, so saving as an xls isn't an option, as the sheets aren't large enough to hold where my data is. There are plenty of volatile functions [INDIRECT() mainly] in the file, so that is worthy of investigation. How would I diagnose if it is an event triggering?

Comment: Aside from saving it as a non macro file you could do 'Application.EnableEvents = False' in the immediate window. This should turn off all events. There are also security settings, or manually checking every single folder in the VB project and adding breakpoints.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. The issue turned out to be a volatile action that a macro was triggering. I had a macro that looped through hiding empty rows, but hiding a row is volatile, so then triggers a new calculation before the next run through the loop. The loop itself was 500 iterations, so that meant 500 sets of 3 second calculations! Happy to mark as answer if you rephrase to focus on volatile actions!

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb687891(v=office.15).aspx

Answer (score 1):

The issue turned out to be a volatile action that a macro was triggering. I had a macro that looped through hiding empty rows, but hiding a row is volatile, so then triggers a new calculation before the next run through the loop. The loop itself was 500 iterations, so that meant 500 sets of 3 second calculations!

See this link for more on volatile actions:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb687891(v=office.15).aspx